# SQL Progress column not found

Tags: sql, openedge, progress-db

I have this query:

```
SELECT spechist.item,image."image-path",image."image-item",image."image-source" 
FROM PUB.spechist left outer join PUB.image on (image."image-item"=spechist.item) 
WHERE (spechist."photocard-display"=yes) AND (spechist."rec-type"='I') and (spechist.item='111')
```

For some reason I get this error when i run the query:

**error message**

`[MERANT][ODBC PROGRESS driver][PROGRESS]Column not found/specified (7520)`

When I remove the following from the query it runs fine:

```
WHERE (spechist."photocard-display"=yes) AND (spechist."rec-type"='I') and (spechist.item='111')
```

I know for a fact those columns are in the table. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: try removing double quote on spechist."photocard-display"  AND spechist."rec-type"

Comment: Can you please show us the schemea for this table? Using `\d+ PUB.spechist`

Answer (score 0):

With out seeing your schema I can't tell for sure but here are some things to try.

1. Is the capitalization correct?
2. Do you need to use the full table name PUB.spechist
3. Does it work with any of those three restrictions in the where clause? Try adding them one at a time and see which one stops execution.

Comment: I'm using SQL92 progress so I have to use double quotes for those columns that have a dash (-) in the name. Also I have to use the full table name PUB.spechist for proper SQL92 syntax.
Also I tried removing one column at a time like David Walters suggested and I found out that the following is the one giving me problems:

(spechist."photocard-display"=yes)

I can confirm that column exists and the capitalization is correct.

Comment: =yes may be your problem.  Try =true instead.